# Robocopy $lastexitcode/$? inconsistent behaviors depending if the destination path is local or on a server

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am trying to use robocopy to copy some files between folders. Upon completion of the code, I want to trigger something else. In my code, I have tried to use $lastexitcode/$? to identify if robocopy has run successfully. When it completes and nothing more needs to get copied, it should return "$lastexitcode/$?: True/0". But I noticed that it behaves differently depending on if the destination path is local or on a server.

A

```
while ($true) {
  robocopy C:\Users\Desktop\1 C:\user\desktop\tmp *
  write-host $? $LASTEXITCODE
}
```

B

```
while ($true) {
  robocopy C:\Users\Desktop\1 \\ABC\tmp *
  write-host $? $LASTEXITCODE
}
```

For code A, the console returns "False 1" when first time it completes copying and "True 0" in the subsequent runs. 
But for code B, the console returns "False 1" even in subsequent runs.

Anyone encountered similar issues and any advice about circumvent this?

Thanks
Tornar

Comment: `robocopy` uses some of the non-zero exit codes (values below 8) to communicate non-error status information. The automatic variable `$?` contains a boolean value indicating whether or not the last command was run successfully, which is mostly useful with PowerShell cmdlets, but less so with external commands.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/954404/return-codes-that-are-used-by-the-robocopy-utility-in-windows-server-2

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I know what each error code is about from powershell. That is not what I am asking. And I am not using any external code.

Comment: @DavidBrabant thanks for post this, but that is not what I am asking.

Comment: @Tornar Sorry, misunderstood your question. You *are* using an external command, though. `robocopy` is an executable, not a PowerShell cmdlet.

Comment: Can you provide output of 2 subsequent command runs for each example?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, no worries. I didn't know robocopy is not part of Powershell. 

For code A, it prints "True 0"
For code B, it prints "False 1"

Comment: Is code B copying to a file system which does not represent file dates or times to the same level of precision?

Comment: @BaconBits yes, it was a precision thing. I have added /DST /FFT and now it is working. Thanks!

Comment: I meant the `robocopy` output, not the output from your `Write-Host` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bacon Bits, The issue got resolved after adding some parameters:

```
while ($true) {
  robocopy C:\Users\Desktop\1 \\ABC\tmp * /DST /FFT
  write-host $? $LASTEXITCODE
}
```